# Function pointer inside struct in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand C syntax and I have done the following example. I have placed a function pointer `*func` as a property of my `Person` struct, which returns a `struct Person`.

```
typedef struct
{
    int age, salary;
    struct Person(*func) (int age, int salary);
} Person;

Person other_func(int age, int salary)
{
    Person* person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    person->age = age;
    person->salary = salary;
    return *person;
};

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.func= other_func;
    p = p.func(30, 3000);
}
```

This gives me "Can not convert Person to Person" on the last line. I suppose this is because the one is `Person` and the second is `struct Person`, but inside the `Person` struct, I have have my function as `struct Person(*func_1) (int age, int salary);` because it raises a compilation time error if I use `Person` instead of `struct Person`. So I used `struct Person` instead. Is this the problem ? How would I achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: Try changing the very first line to `typedef struct Person`.

Comment: also this implementation has memory leak.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you explain where exactly is the memory leak ? because i do not see it

Comment: Don't use `typedef` and you should be ok (after the necessary changes).

Comment: memory leak: 1 `malloc()`, 0 `free()` ... BTW, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: BTW, `other_func()` leaks memory because the person pointer is lost. You can't take the address of the returned value and free that because a copy is made.

Comment: `Person* person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    person->age = age;` change to `Person person = {age, salary}; return person;` no need `malloc`. because you return `Person`(copy) Without release `parson`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct
{
    int age, salary;
    struct Person(*func) (int age, int salary);
} Person;
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
typedef struct Person
{
    int age, salary;
    struct Person(*func) (int age, int salary);
} Person;
```

In the first case, you don't name your struct, so `struct Person` isn't a valid type name. My version of GCC gives more helpful output:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:20:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     p.func= other_func;
           ^
test.c:21:5: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Person’
     p = p.func(30, 3000);
```

Note that the two names don't need to match. All you're doing is combining a typedef and a struct declaration. This is would be equally valid:

```
struct X {
    int age, salary;
    struct X(*func) (int age, int salary);
};

typedef struct X Person;
```

You may want to read [this excellent answer about struct typedef'ing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446/212555).

Comment: you are right. what exactly is the difference between the two ? I thought it was exactly the same ?

Comment: For anyone else wondering why defining a type like this isn't an error, [it's because this is how you do forward declaration in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and).

Answer (score 2):

*typedef struct X {} Y;*

*X* - is a TAG which you can convert to something useful with syntax '*struct X val*'. *Y* is typename which you can use directly: *'Y val;'*

Then, type name Y (in your case 'Person' is not visible inside of struct as it is defined later. That is why you have to use TAG inside of struct:

```
typedef struct tag_Person {
    struct tag_Person (*func)(int arge, int salary);
} Person;
```

Comment: I don't think the tag/ type name distinction is correct (they are both type names), but you're right that the second one isn't available yet.