# Linked list library

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to implement a linked list library, where every node has the type of the list. For example, the create function looks "normal" :

```
int LstCreate(LIST_ENTRY **List);
```

but GetNodeValue presents the Node as a list:

```
int LstGetNodeValue(LIST_ENTRY *Node, int *Value);

int LstGetNthNode(LIST_ENTRY *List, int Index, LIST_ENTRY **Node);
```

How can I implement such a list ?
My first idea was that the list is a structure that has only the head node in it like this:

```
struct LIST_ENTRY
{
   int Value;
   LIST_ENTRY *Next;
};
```

but then the list would have to be the head of the list every time.

The structure can't look like this:

```
struct Node
{
   int Value;
   Node *Next;
}

struct LIST_ENTRY
{
   struct Node *Head;
   struct Node *CurrentNode;
   struct Node *Tail;
   ...
}
```

because the Node has to have the SAME TYPE as the List.

Comment: Random access on a linked list `LstGetNthNode` is awkward and slow. A different data structure should be used if if random access is used. Also, your proposed structure looks fine, I don't know what you mean by "list is a structure that has only the head node in it".

Comment: @AluanHaddad Let's say I use that structure and I call LstCreate(List),  what the function would do is allocate memory for one node (which I don't actually have). In other words, LstCreate should allocate memory for a list,  not for the first node, then when I call LstInsert I would allocate memory for the first Node and so on.

Comment: Why would `LstCreate` allocate memory?

Comment: @Liviu a linked list is arbitrarily long. All you need is to store the head of the list. That might warrant creating a structure that wraps it but it depends on how you expect to the list to be consumed.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I edited my answer, it should be more clear now. If the Node wouldn't have the same type as the list, that is how the structure would have to look.

Comment: @Liviu check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658664/1915893

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Your "first idea" is correct. What more do you need?

Comment: Why do you need `struct Node`? I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: @melpomene The LstCreate could look like this if I implement my first idea:    int LstCreate(LIST_ENTRY **List)
 {
  *List = malloc(sizeof(LIST_ENTRY));
 
  if (!(*List))
   return -1;

  (*List)->Value = 0;
  (*List)->Next = NULL;

  return 0;
 }
but that would create the head node, and we don't know what value it should  take.

Comment: @Liviu No, it should be `int LstCreate(LIST_ENTRY **pp) { *pp = NULL; return 0; }`.

Comment: @melpomene I was thinking too much about "allocating" the list and I didn't realise that was the way to go. Thank you !