# C - Unknown type name

Tags: c, struct

I need to build a "social network" for college, but I always get unknown type name 'List' while compiling. I removed a lot of functions from my headers, but I still get the same error and I don't know why.
I've got 3 headers:

My friend's header

```
#ifndef FRIEND_H
#define FRIEND_H

#include "ListHeadTail.h"

typedef struct Friend{
    int id;
    struct Friend *nextFriend;
}Friend;

void printFriends(List *l);
void removeFriend(List *l);
void addFriend(List *l);

#endif /* FRIEND_H */
```

My list header:

```
#ifndef LISTHEADTAIL_H
#define LISTHEADTAIL_H

#include "Student.h"

typedef struct pStudent{
    struct pStudent *ant;
    Student *s;
    struct pStudent *prox;
}pStudent;

typedef struct list{
    pStudent *head;
    pStudent *tail;
}List;

void startList(List *l);
void printList(List *l);
void freeList(List *l);

#endif /* LISTHEADTAIL_H */
```

My student's header

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#define MAX 51

#include "Friend.h"
#include "ListHeadTail.h"

typedef struct Student{
    int id;
    char name[MAX];
    Friend *friends;
}Student;

Student* readStudent ();
void printStudent(Student* a);
void changeData(List *l);

#endif /* STUDENT_H */
```

My main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "ListHeadTail.h"
#include "Friend.h"
#include "Student.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    List l;

    startList(&l);

    freeList(&l);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your `main` first includes `ListHeadTail.h` which will include `Student.h`. Then `Student.h` will include `Friend.h`, all in that order. `Student.h` will attempt to use what's defined in `ListHeadTail.h` before it's actually defined (the complete body of `ListHeadTail.h` hasn't been parsed yet). When you have a circular dependency, you need to use [forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and).

Comment: You're correct. I've just changed my code and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the (first) error I get when I try to compile this set of files:

```
$ cc main.c
In file included from main.c:4:
In file included from ./ListHeadTail.h:4:
In file included from ./Student.h:6:
./Friend.h:11:19: error: unknown type name 'List'
void printFriends(List *l);
```

Look at the file names and line numbers.  Note that at ListHeadTail.h line 4, you've already defined `LISTHEADTAIL_H`, but you haven't yet reached the actual declaration of `List`.  You then go into Student.h, and from there into Friend.h.  That includes ListHeadTail.h again -- but since `LISTHEADTAIL_H` is already defined, this include does nothing.  So you continue through Friend.h with no declaration of `List`, and therefore get an error on the declarations that reference it.

As noted by @lurker in their comment, the basic issue here is circular dependency, and a simple fix is forward declaration.  In this case, you could simply modify Friend.H, replacing `#include "ListHeadTail.h"` with `typedef struct list List;`.

But to me this is a bit hacky.  If you shift the order of includes somewhere, the build might break again.

I think the real problem is that the declarations of the functions (`printFriends`, etc.) don't belong in Friend.h; they belong in ListHeadTail.h.  The functions have nothing to do with the `Friend` type.  Sure, they have "Friend" in their names, but the only type referenced in the declarations is `List`.  So they belong in ListHeadTail.h.  Same goes for the `changeData` function in Student.h.

In an object-oriented design (say, in Java), these functions would all probably be methods of the List class, and would be declared in that class's source file.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, those functions have nothing to do with the Friend type, I'll try to change my code so my Friend type gets only functions related to Friend. Thank you.