# How can I define two structs, each one used in the second one ? C language

Tags: c, struct, compilation

Can i define two struct and use each one in the other one?
my code below .

I try to use typedef, but not working.

```
struct Book{
int isbn;
char title[21];
//This is Auther struct usage;
struct Auther bauther[21];
int numofauth;
char section[21];
int copies;
};

struct Auther{
char auth_name[21];
//This is Book struct usage;
struct Book auth_books[21];
};
```

J:\Collage_Library\main.c|23|error: redefinition of 'struct Auther'|

Comment: Have your read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example with a one-by-one reference.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

struct Book {
    char title[21];
    struct Auth *auth;
};

struct Auth {
    char name[21];
    struct Book *book;
};


int main(void)
{  
    struct Auth a = { "People of God" , NULL };
    struct Book b = { "42-line Bible", &a };
    a.book = &b;

    printf("book title:  %s\r\n", b.title);
    printf("book author: %s\r\n", b.auth->name);

    printf("auth name:   %s\r\n", a.name);
    printf("auth book:   %s\r\n", a.book->title);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A `struct` cannot be inside another `struct` that is inside the first `struct`, for the same reason that in the real world you cannot put an object inside another object inside the first object.

An object can refer to another object using a pointer.

For example, a `struct Book` could have a member that is a pointer to a `struct Author` or that is an array of pointers to `struct Author`. That could be declared like this:

```
struct Book
{
    int isbn;
    char title[21];
    struct Author *bauthor[21]; // Array of pointers to struct Author.
    int numofauth;
    char section[21];
    int copies;
};
```

Similarly, the `struct Author` could contain pointers to `struct Book`:

```
struct Author
{
    char auth_name[21];
    struct Book *auth_books[21]; // Array of pointers to struct Book.
};
```

When you create `struct Book` or `struct Author` objects, you will have to fill in the pointers. To do this, you will have to create each of the structures and then assign values to the pointers. For example:

```
struct Book *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
if (b == NULL) ReportErrorAndExit();
struct Author *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
if (a == NULL) ReportErrorAndExit();

b->isbn = 1234;
strcpy(b->title, "Forward Declarations");
b->bauthor[0] = a; // List a as one of b's authors.
b->numofauth = 1;
strcpy(b->section, "Structures");
b->copies = 1;

strcpy(a->auth_name, "C committee");
a->auth_books[0] = b; // List b as one of a's books.
```