# is it possible for two different recursive voids to call each other in C?

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, void

i am trying to use two recursive that depend on each other in C but when i compile i get this error :

`In function 'void Horizontal(int* (*)[1000], int, int, int*)':`

`[Error] 'Vertical' was not declared in this scope`

and if i swap vertical and horizontal , horizontal becomes undeclared in this scope

here is the code i wrote :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
 void Horizontal(int*m[][1000],int i,int j,int*cpt)
 {
    if(*m[i][j]!=0)
    {
        *m[i][j]=0;
        *cpt++;
        Vertical(&*m,i,j,&*cpt);
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j-1,&*cpt);
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j+1,&*cpt);
    }
 }
 void Vertical(int*m[][1000],int i,int j,int*cpt)
 {
    if(*m[i][j]!=0)
    {
        *m[i][j]=0;
        *cpt++;
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j,&*cpt);
        Vertical(&*m,i-1,j,&*cpt);
        Vertical(&*m,i+1,j,&*cpt);
    }
 }
 int main()
 {

 }
```

the int main() is empty because i just wanted to check my syntax

Comment: It's possible to get this to compile, as the answers say. But the way you wrote it, the call to `Vertical` from `Horizontal` is guaranteed to do nothing (because the `if` in `Vertical` will not be entered), and likewise for the call to `Horizontal` from `Vertical`.

Comment: Tip: `&*cpt` is a weird way of writing `cpt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can, but you need to *forward declare* the function.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration
- [What is 'forward declaration' and the difference between 'typedef struct X' and 'struct X'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and)

Like so:

```
// Forward declaration:

void Horizontal( int* m[][1000], int i, int j, int* cpt );

void Vertical( int* m[][1000], int i, int j, int* cpt );

// Function implementation:

void Horizontal(int*m[][1000],int i,int j,int*cpt)
 {
    if(*m[i][j]!=0)
    {
        *m[i][j]=0;
        *cpt++;
        Vertical(&*m,i,j,&*cpt);
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j-1,&*cpt);
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j+1,&*cpt);
    }
 }
 void Vertical(int*m[][1000],int i,int j,int*cpt)
 {
    if(*m[i][j]!=0)
    {
        *m[i][j]=0;
        *cpt++;
        Horizontal(&*m,i,j,&*cpt);
        Vertical(&*m,i-1,j,&*cpt);
        Vertical(&*m,i+1,j,&*cpt);
    }
 }
```

To allow other `*.c` files to use these functions you place these forward-declarations in a separate file (the header file) and let your other `*.c` files use that header file and the linker takes care of the rest.

Comment: thank you Dai it worked i will take it as an answer as soon as the site lets me

Comment: (Technically, the forward decl of `Horizontal` isn't needed.)

Comment: @ikegami Indeed, but I included it anyway given the possibility of wanting to export both functions in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare your function. Add this before the `Horizontal` function:

```
void Vertical(int*[][1000],int,int,int*);
```