# How to define a typedef struct inside another one with anonymous union?

Tags: c, typedef

I want to represent a nested ast node

```c
typedef struct ast_assignment
{
    char* sym;
    ast_node* value;
} ast_assignment;

typedef struct ast_conjunction
{
    char* sym;
    ast_node* value;
} ast_conjunction;

typedef struct ast_node {
  int node_type;
  union {
    ast_assignment data;
    ast_conjunction data;
  };
} ast_node;
```

but no matter what I define first, the compiler tells me that the other struct is an unknown type? How to proceed?

Comment: *Which* other struct? This code doesn't look like it will compile - it requires a semicolon after the closing `}` of each typedef, and none of the typedef actually provide a name.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and).

Comment: Sorry copy pasted some snipets for demonstration. usually the first request is for code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Typedef has to describe an actual type name
- Typedefs require a `;` after them
- Circular type references require a bit of special sauce
- Unions require different member names

Might you mean:

```c
struct ast_node; // forward declaration

typedef struct {
    char* sym;
    struct ast_node* value;
} ast_assignment;

typedef struct ast_conjunction {
    char  * sym;
    struct ast_node* value;
} ast_conjunction;

typedef struct ast_node {
    int node_type;
    union {
        ast_assignment  data_asg;
        ast_conjunction data_conj;
    };
} ast_node;
```

Expanding on this a bit for a more complete answer.

First, the purpose of a typedef is to install a new name into the compiler that you can use, so `typedef struct { ... };` doesn't really do much. It should be `typedef struct {...} newtype;` so you can use that actual name `newtype`.

It also requires a semicolon after, which messes me up every time I go back from C# to C :-)

The circular reference thing is tricky, and doing `struct mytype;` in advance means you can use that name `mytype` *only if* it's in a context where knowledge of the structure details don't have to be known. In practice, it means you can use the `struct mytype *` as a pointer - because this is a fixed size - but this is not allowed:

```c
struct ast_node; // forward declaration

struct some_other_type {
    struct ast_node *nodeptr;  // this is ok
    struct ast_node  thisnode; // FAIL
    ...
};
```

The reason is: a pointer is a fixed size no matter what kind of data it points to so the compiler carries you a bit, but the `thisnode` would require knowledge of all the details. Sorry, no way to do that.

Re: the union, you can't define any `union` or `struct` with two members with the same name because how could you reference one of them and the compiler would know which?

Personally I'm not a fan of using `typedef` for structure types, so I'd do this as:

```c
struct ast_node; // forward struct defn

struct asg_assignment {
    char *sym;
    struct ast_node *value;
};

struct ast_conjunction {
    char  * sym;
    struct ast_node* value;
};

struct ast_node {
    int node_type;
    union {
        struct ast_assignment  data_asg;
        struct ast_conjunction data_conj;
    };
};
```

... but I'm not sure I can justify this by anything other than personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your code. The correct way to declare a struct is as follows:

```c
struct a {
    ...
};  // needs a semicolon
```

And to refer to it, you must use the `struct` keyword as well;

```c
struct b {
    struct a data;
};
```

---

In your case, the proper code that will compile is:

```c
struct ast_assignment
{
    char* sym;
    struct ast_node* value;
};

struct ast_conjunction
{
    char* sym;
    struct ast_node* value;
};

struct ast_node {
  int node_type;
  union {
    struct ast_assignment data_assignment;
    struct ast_conjunction data_conjunction;  // you cannot have multiple members with the same name
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, the type you want to caöl has to be declared first.

However, you can just use another pointer like `void*`.

`void*` is a pointer that can be used for any type.

If you define type of the later struct in the first struct as `void*`, the compiler will allow it.

**But** this has drawbacks. You are losing type safety with this and you may need to cast at some points.

Also, a `typedef` shortcut does not allow it to be used before the whole the `typedef` is declared.

This means, you can't use the shortcut inside the struct.

For example, the following would not be possible:

```
typedef struct mystruct{
    myStruct_t *myValue;
} myStruct_t;
```

You'll need to do this instead:

```
typedef struct mystruct{
    struct myStruct *myValue;
} myStruct_t;
```

Comment: void would be an option but not in my case, tnx