# include guard does not allow me to declare a type

Tags: c

I encountered such an interesting problem, because of the include guard trigger, the type declared in the header file is not declared.

I have a mutex file.h which describes the mutex_t type, it depends on the thread_t type that is declared in the thread file.h, however, thread_t depends on mutex_t, and the main.c file uses both of these types.

Problem:
when compiling main.c, the thread file is included.h, which includes mutex.h, however, because of the thread.h was already connected, then it rolls out include guard and does not allow declaring the thread_t type in mutex.h

*thread.h*

```
#ifndef _THREAD_H_
#define _THREAD_H_

#include "mutex.h"

typedef struct thread
{
    int thread_data;
} thread_t;

extern mutex_t* get_mutex();

#endif
```

*mutex.h*

```
#ifndef _MUTEX_H_
#define _MUTEX_H_

#include "thread.h"
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct mutex {
    uint8_t      lock_status; //+0
    thread_t*    waiting_thread_queue[1024];
} mutex_t;

extern thread_t* get_thread();

#endif
```

*main.c*

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stddef.h"
#include "thread.h"

int main(void) {
    get_thread();
    get_mutex();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
emilia@emilia-pc:~/test$ gcc main.c
In file included from thread.h:4,
                 from main.c:3:
mutex.h:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘thread_t’
    9 |     thread_t*    waiting_thread_queue[1024];
      |     ^~~~~~~~
mutex.h:12:8: error: unknown type name ‘thread_t’
   12 | extern thread_t* get_thread();
      |        ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Names starting with `_` followed by capital letter are [reserved](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) for compiler use. Change the names of your include guards.

Comment: Why `thread.h` is including `mutex.h` ? There are no dependencies requiring it. Circular includes are evil as you can see

Comment: Add forward declarations for `struct thread_t` and `struct mutex_t`, then get rid of the circular includes. See: [What is 'forward declaration' and the difference between 'typedef struct X' and 'struct X'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and)

Comment: @EugeneSh., I updated the question. Now require.

Comment: @Botje, This is not relevant to the current issue. In this case, include guard does not allow me to do what I require.

Comment: That is the canonical solution to a circular include problem: predeclare types so you don't *have* to do a circular include.

Comment: In the `mutex.h` header file, instead of `#include "thread.h"` do `typedef struct thread thread_t;`. And in the `thread.h` header file instead of `#include "mutex.h"` do `typedef struct mutex mutex_t;` And please do a search for "circular inclusion" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Botje, More information please, what do I need to do and where?

Comment: @mrjbom2 I commented on the include guards while the question still had C++ tag, but your foremost problem is circular include and you have to solve that first. It's not going to work regardless of any include guards.

Comment: You first need to read the answer I linked, then follow @Someprogrammerdude's advice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, It helped me, thank you!
It is strange that this worked because the thread structure or mutex without #include should not be visible.

Comment: @Botje, Yes, I have read your answers, thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see any reason in the world to have `extern mutex_t* get_mutex();` in `thread.h`.  `mutex_t* get_mutex();` should be declared in `mutex.h`.

Comment: That's the point of a *forward declaration*, to make symbols visible (to the compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between two headers. The thread header needs mutex and *vice versa*.

The way you have done it doesn't make sense. The thread header declares a function called `get_mutex`, and *vice versa*, the mutex header declares a function called `get_thread`.

Probably, what this points to is that the headers are so closely related, they should be one header.

Anyway, the way we can break a circular dependency is by using a forward declaration in one of the headers.

```
// child.h
struct parent; // incomplete "forward" declaration
struct child {
  struct parent *parent;
};

// parent.h
#include "child.h"
#define MAX_CHILDREN 42
struct parent {
  struct child *children[MAX_CHILDREN];
};
```

The "forward" declaration `struct parent` doesn't require the `parent.h` header. The `parent.h` header picks up that declaration, but it does not interfere with its own declaration, because this is allowed:

```
struct parent;

struct parent { ... };
```

Note that `_THREAD_H_` intrudes into a reserved implementation namespace. Names beginning with an underscore followed by either a capital letter or another underscore are reserved. Violating this rule is actually undefined behavior, which can have any consequences whatsoever. The implementation can stop translating your program with a diagnostic message. Or it can predefine a macro called `_THREAD_H_`, so that your own header fails to produce its expected contents.