# How to declare a function pointer in a struct, which the function that pointer points includes that struct in its body?

Tags: c, struct

I tried to search quite a lot but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

For example:

```
struct A {
 int something;
 void(*function_ptr)(void);
 function_ptr = function;
}

void function(void) {
struct A sth;
}
```

As you can see, I cannot define the function before struct since it contains that struct in its body, but when I define the struct before, I can't point to that function since it hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: `sth.function_ptr = function` inside `function` acceptable for your requirements?

Comment: You cannot have an assignment inside the structure definition. You may want something like that: `struct A sth = {42, function};` where the declaration of the `function` is visible.

Comment: I could do that but i still need something represents that function in struct A.

Comment: Well, you could make use of forward declaration (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and ), but it seems an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: So how do i point that function in my struct A.

Comment: *i still need something represents that function in struct A*. What do you mean? The first two comments do exactly that. It sets the `function_ptr` to point to `function` in a struct A variable.

Comment: I want to have it in struct A. Not struct A sth

Comment: @namenamename you cannot. It makes  absolutely no sense. You cannot build a house inside an email message, or add lemon juice into a joke, or paint an idea in red colour.

Comment: Do you know that what you are writing is not C? In C you cannot initialize struct values inside a struct definition.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

struct A {
  int something;
  void(*function_ptr)(void);
};

void function(void) {
  struct A sth;
  // possibly use sth somewhere here

  printf("Hello I'm in function\n");
}

int main()
{
  struct A a;
  a.function_ptr = function;
  a.function_ptr();
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
  struct A a = {0 , function };  // a.something = 0; a.function_ptr = function;
  a.function_ptr();
}
```

or even something like this:

```
struct A* NewstructA()
{
  struct A* newstruct = malloc(sizeof(*newstruct));
  newstruct->function_ptr = function;
}

int main()
{
  struct A* a = NewstructA();
  (a->function_ptr)();
}
```

Comment: Thanks i can make use of it but im planning to malloc a lot of those structs so i dont want to initialize them after that, maybe i can do what i want with extern's.

Comment: Write a function that does the malloc and the initialisation

Comment: I'll do that if i can't make it any simpler