# Forward declaration without using the class keyword

Tags: c++

```
class Wheel
{
    Car* car;
};

int main(){
 return  0;
}
```

Above code does not compile however if I add a `class` keyword then the compilation works:

```
class Wheel
{
    class Car* car;
};
```

Why does't the first example compile? I also understand the following is another way of accomplishing this:

```
class Car;
class Wheel
{
   Car* car;
};
```

Comment: Why should it compile? You've used an undefined typename and you haven't forward-declared it. That's not legal in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you, the compiler reads from the top to the bottom. If you have an object pointer of a class without ever declaring said class, the compiler (like you) goes "wait, what is this class?"

---

(The compiler says "what is this" like:

```
error: ‘Car’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘char’?
```

It is saying, i don't know this type, how can i declare a pointer to it. It is even trying to be helpful with a suggestion, how cute!)

---

So you need forward declarations, and they are allowed specifically for this reason.

Comment: so in the second  example `class Car* car;` is essentially forward declaring it within `Wheel`? and the third example is  forward declaring it outside?

Comment: Yep, both are simply forward declarations. The second way is preferred, because it is clearer that this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use this kind of implicit forward declaration. It's unusual, **confusing** and can be wrong.

```
class Wheel
{
    class Car* car; // 1
};
```

So is this declaring `::Car` or `Wheel::Car`? And to be honest it doesn't even matter. What matters is that the vast majority of people won't know the answer and they will either have to guess or do extensive research to find out.

In this case it declares `::Car`.

And now comes the fun part:

```
class Wheel
{
    class Car* car; // 1

    class Car {};   // 2
};
```

Is `Car` in 1 and 2 the same? **No!!** 1 is still declaring `::Car` while 2 is obviously a definition of `Wheel::Car`.

Let's expand the fun. Oh boy!

```
class Wheel
{
    class Car* car_1; // 1

    class Car {};     // 2

    Car* car_3;       // 3
    class Car* car_4; // 4
};
```

Is your head spining yet?

1 is `::Car`, while 2, 3, and 4 are `Wheel::Car`. Please notice how 1 and 4 look exactly **identical**, but the variables have 2 completely **different** types.

Even more fun:

```
class Wheel
{
    class Car {};   // 1

    class Car* car; // 2
};
```

Now 2 doesn't contain a forward declaration and the type is `Wheel::Car`. Please notice how 2 looks identical with the first example but is very  different.

In conclusion don't use this!

Comment: I guess this is more like a C style of declaring it for structs, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658438/what-is-forward-declaration-and-the-difference-between-typedef-struct-x-and

Comment: @Dan I don't care. This is C++ and C++ is different than C and has different idioms and best practices.